# qemu-virgil shows OpenGL is not supported by the display

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, kde

I am trying to emulate Plasma Mobile iso on VM. In the docs of plasma mobile, its written to use qemu-vrigil. 
I installed qemu-virgil from snap.
But when I use qemu-virgil I get this error

```
qemu-system-x86_64: egl: eglGetDisplay failed
qemu-system-x86_64: OpenGL is not supported by the display
```

#### Attempt to solve the issue

I seached for enabling OpenGL support for qemu. From the [qemu docs](https://at.projects.genivi.org/wiki/display/GDP/QEMU+with+hardware+graphics+acceleration) I was able to build `qemu-system-x86_64` which supported OpenGL, but qemu-virgil uses its own executable.

PS: Plasma Mobile docs : https://docs.plasma-mobile.org/DevGuide.html

My system

Desktop Environment : Kde Neon 5.16.1

Graphic Card: Nvidia GTX 1050Ti